# How to delete all TFS workspaces of a user in one go

Tags: tfs, workspace

I want to create a batch file that deletes all TFS workspaces of a user. This will be used in scenarios when a person is leaving the organization.

Is there a command in TFS which allows me to delete all workspaces of a user in one go? I do not want to first get workspaces and then delete them one by one, because then it will require manual intervention.

if something like this could be possible
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>tf workspace /server:<servername> /delete *;<domain>\<username>

The command above does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) from Attrice can do this

Comment: Thanks Betty, I will check this tool. If this tool can do this, it means there is surely a command that can be run via command line. I just don't know what it is

Comment: I checked, the software also first lists all workspaces and then one has to manually delete one by one :(

Comment: Pity, still it has to be faster than doing it via commandline manually.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of [Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) (5.0) allows you to delete multiple workspaces. I just purged 4218 workspaces.

Comment: Please keep in mind that "the current version" is prone to change. It would be better if you stated explicitly which version you are referring to.